# AxShockwaveFlashObjects again

Tags: .net, flash, activex, ocx

I was cheating from a sample program to integrate with Flash.
I able to add a reference to ShockwaveFlashObjects.dll to my windows app, but

What is 
1- AXShockwaveFlashObjects.
2- How to add a reference to it, or I have to create it using some tool?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not a Flash expert but I was researching something similar and I might have some information to help you...

**AxShockwaveFlashObjects** is a COM library to allow you to integrate Flash content into your COM (or .NET) application. I'm guessing you've already seen the sample app here: [www.csharphelp.com/2006/02/using-flash-with-c/](http://www.csharphelp.com/2006/02/using-flash-with-c/)

It appears that even if you have added the component correctly in Visual Studio,  an error can still occur when running the program. The workaround (given [here](http://blogs.vbcity.com/drydo/archive/2005/12/07/5731.aspx)) is simply to include the AxShockwaveFlashObjects DLL in your application directory. (You can download the DLL via that link too.)

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 4):

You can simply add

```
<COMReference Include="AxShockwaveFlashObjects">
  <Guid>{D27CDB6B-AE6D-11CF-96B8-444553540000}</Guid>
  <VersionMajor>1</VersionMajor>
  <VersionMinor>0</VersionMinor>
  <Lcid>0</Lcid>
  <WrapperTool>aximp</WrapperTool>
  <Isolated>False</Isolated>
</COMReference>
```

to your project file just after ShockwaveFlashObjects

Comment: This worked when nothing else did.  Thanks!  I would appreciate knowing why, though.  If anyone has an idea why this would have to pasted in manually, I would like to hear about it.