# WPF VB.NET Play flash .swf file in page

Tags: wpf, vb.net, flash

How can I add swf player into my page? Can I use the media element as I play video on WPF? This is not WPF for browser. It's for normal windows use. Not browser

[image: See here]

Someone please help me how to play swf in WPF..

Answer (score 1):

You have two possibilities:

1) Use a WebBrowser and navigate to a swf file (local or remote)
2) Use com as described here: [AxShockwaveFlashObjects again](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2400686/axshockwaveflashobjects-again)

Comment: Someone help me. Im not browser background. I don't see Shockwave object in WPF toolbox. But in COM component, I already selected it